# Separatedness of a scheme of finite type over a field

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be a field.
Let $\bar k$ be an algebraic closure of $k$.
Let $X$ be a $k$-scheme of finite type.
Suppose $X\times_k \bar k$ is separated over $\bar k$.
Is $X$ separated over $k$?
If yes, how do you prove it?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\overline{X}$ denote $X \times_k \bar{k}$. Then this statement is true if $\overline{X} \to X$ is a closed and surjective morphism. My intuition tells me this is true because $X$ should be the quotient of $\overline{X}$ by the Galois action, but I'm not sure yet. I'll edit this post when I figure that out, but assuming it, then we can prove this as follows. You can verify that the diagram

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\overline{X} @>>> X \\
@VVV @VVV \\
\overline{X} \times_\bar{k} \overline{X} @>>> X \times_k X
\end{CD}
$$

is cartesian where the vertical morphisms are the diagonals and the horizontal morphisms are the natural ones induced by base extension. The horizontal morphisms are closed and $\Delta_\overline{X}$ is closed by assumption, and the top morphism is surjective, so the diagonal $\Delta_X$ must be closed.