# Preservation of separatedness of a scheme of finite type over a field by shrinking the base field

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is a generalization of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/616961/separatedness-of-a-scheme-of-finite-type-over-a-field).
Let $k$ be a field.
Let $k'$ be an extension field of $k$.
Let $X$ be a $k$-scheme of finite type.
Suppose $X\times_k k'$ is separated over $k'$.
Is $X$ separated over $k$?
If yes, how do you prove it?

Comment: I think same argument I posted in that other answer should work for any field extension as long as the projection $X_{k'} \to X$ is closed and surjective. I'm still not sure if/when this will true but it seems true for e.g. algebraic extensions in characteristic $0$.

Comment: @DoriBejleri Please see [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/617711/examples-that-the-morphism-x-times-k-k-rightarrow-x-is-not-closed).

Comment: Ok so it is true when the extension is algebraic. Cool, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Formation of the diagonal is compatible with base-change; i.e. the base-change
to $k'$ of the diagonal morphism $X \to X\times_k X$ is canonically identified with the diagonal morphism $X' \to X' \times_{k'} X'$.  (Here I have written
$X' := X\times_k k'$.)

Now $X$ is separated over $k$ iff the diagonal is a closed immersion, and
so what we want to check is that $Y \to X$ is a closed immersion iff
the base-changed morphism $Y' \to X'$ is closed immersion.

This latter statement is true, and not too hard to check.  Indeed,
the property of being a closed immersion can be checked after making
any faithfully flat quasi-compact base-change (one says that the property of being
a closed immersion satisfies *fpqc descent*).