# Examples that the morphism $X\times_k k' \rightarrow X$ is not closed

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be a field.
Let $k'$ be an extension field of $k$.
Let $X$ be a $k$-scheme of finite type.
If $k'$ is algebraic over $k$, the morphism $X\times_k k' \rightarrow X$ is integral.
Hence it is closed.
Suppose $k'$ is not algebraic over $k$.
I would like to know examples, if any, that the morphism $X\times_k k' \rightarrow X$ is not closed.

Comment: @Benja No. I mean a closed morphism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $\mbox{Spec}(k(z)[x])\to\mbox{Spec}(k[x])$ induced by the inclusion $k[x]\hookrightarrow k(z)[x]$. Then the maximal ideal $(x-z)$ is sent to the generic point of $\mbox{Spec}(k[x])$.